# Atom Package - [workspaceElement, activationPromise] = []

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine, atom-editor

In spec (test) part of Atom packages, there seems to be the convention to initialize variables like this:

```
[workspaceElement, activationPromise] = []
[workspaceElement, initialActiveItem, otherItem1, otherItem2] = []
```

This seems to be translated to Vanilla JS as:

```
var initialActiveItem, otherItem1, otherItem2, ref, workspaceElement;

ref = [], workspaceElement = ref[0], initialActiveItem = ref[1], otherItem1 = ref[2], otherItem2 = ref[3];
```

But then subsequently these variables are initialized individually like so:

```
initialActiveItem = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()
```

They are also used separately. So, what's the point of the assignment statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself.

In Jasmine, these variables are used in setup/teardowns like `beforeEach` function. They are also used in actually test cases. As such they have to be attached to the lexical scope of the suite.

This can't be done naturally with CoffeeScript as there's no direct access to `var`, unless one uses backtick Vanilla block.

So `[var1, var2...] = []` is the idiom to declare var in current scope.